# How to add an overlay to view the selected values in UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have created a `UIPickerView` and I want to add an overlay view to show the user what he has selected. I don't know how to add it. Is there any property for that?
For example when we are selecting a date some overlay view will be there in the middle of `UIPickerView`, How should I get that ?

like:  http://www.inexika.com/blog/Customizing-UIPickerView-UIDatePicker

Comment: According to the link you provided there is no overlay view in it....

Comment: @Gill  at the center of the `UIPickerView` one glass kind of view is there right, that one i need.

Comment: That "Glass" is actually the inbuilt selector of the UIPickerView... You can't take it out ... But wat do u want to do with it ??

Comment: @Gill In my `UIPickerView` I am not getting that "Glass". How to get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `UIPickerView` , define 
Add

```
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
```

and use the following method :-

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
}
```

Now in this add a `UIView` which you can call here, or just allocate it here itself adding what you want to `addSubView` in the `UIView`. Hope this much information is sufficient otherwise please tell . Thanks :)

Comment: Can you explain it clearly for the first screenshot in the above link?

Comment: The method I provided will be called when ur uipickerview has selected a particular date ... So you will have to make a uiview in this ... got the idea ??

Comment: Use this pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES; where you allocate your UIPickerView. This will show the glas section .... if thats what you want...